# nginx reverse proxy: hide client identity and IP address for wix

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

This is my  first post in this community.

I am hosting a website in Wix and want to restrict access to a certain number of individuals. In addition, I want everyone to pass my nginx-reverse proxy before the traffic hits Wix. I configured DNS Domains, Nginx and some IP Blocking modules in Wix.

So far so good - my client access works:

///
Client (IP 1.1.1.1) -> Nginx Rev. Proxy (2.2.2.2) -> Wix
///

However, Wix still is able to decode the real IP of my Client (1.1.1.1)
instead of the one of my nginx (2.2.2.2).

This is part of my nginx configuration:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 2.2.2.2;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For "2.2.2.2";
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass_request_headers      off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

Did I miss something?